# We are asked to create python code using qiskit to create a quantum program that prepares the four Bell states

Tags: qiskit, textbook-and-exercises

Then we are asked to show that the following circuit can correctly distinguish between the four Bell states by showing that unique measurements are created for each of the four Bell states. [image]

I have the code to prepare the bell states. But I am not sure how to do the following in code? Do I do to the demonstration in code? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If you have the state $|\psi_1 \rangle = \dfrac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}  $ which is generated by the circuit

[image]

then applying the circuit you indicated in the question (reversed of the Bell state prep circuit) then all the gate cancel out and so upon measurement you will get a $|00\rangle$. That is:

[image]

---

Similarly, you should be able to show that applying the indicated circuit in your question to the other bell states will lead to either $|01\rangle, |10\rangle, |11\rangle$.

So show that upon measurement, these are the results that you get, and each of them correspond to a particular Bell state.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.